# ionic capacitor run android : Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: angular, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have created an Ionic 6.19.1 application with the following variables.gradle file and the "ionic capacitor run android" command works perfectly and the application works perfectly:

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.2.0
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.2.0
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.1.0
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.3.2
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.3.0
    junitVersion = '4.13.1
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.3.0
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '7.0.0'
}
```

but if I replace compileSdkVersion = 30 with compileSdkVersion = 26, the "ionic capacitor run android" command produces this error:

```
 > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
[capacitor] /Users/christophe/Documents/Sources/sylva/sycub/node_modules/@capacitor/app/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/plugins/app/AppPlugin.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
[capacitor] if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
[capacitor] ^
[capacitor] symbol: variable P
[capacitor] location: class VERSION_CODES
[capacitor] /Users/christophe/Documents/Sources/sylva/sycub/node_modules/@capacitor/app/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/plugins/app/AppPlugin.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
[capacitor] data.put("build", Long.toString(pinfo.getLongVersionCode()));
[capacitor] ^
[capacitor] symbol: method getLongVersionCode()
[capacitor] location: variable pinfo of type PackageInfo
[capacitor] 2 errors
[capacitor]         
[capacitor] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor] * What went wrong:
[capacitor] Execution failed for task ':capacitor-app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[capacitor] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor] * Try:
[capacitor] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[capacitor] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[capacitor] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[capacitor]         
[capacitor] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor] You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor] See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[capacitor] 131 actionable tasks: 36 executed, 95 up-to-date
[capacitor]         
[capacitor] BUILD FAILED in 1s
[capacitor]         
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

Java version is "17" 2021-09-14 LTS

Gradle has been updated in Android Studio

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

`compileSdkVersion` is the version of the SDK used to compile your app.
If you use `compileSdkVersion` 26 you are using the SDK that was released for android 8 (Android O), so it doesn’t understand what `VERSION_CODES.P` means, because Android P was launched after Android O and didn’t exist on Android O SDK.

You shouldn’t use `compileSdkVersion` 26, the `compileSdkVersion` is configurable so you can use newer versions if needed, but never older versions.

Not really sure why do you want to do that, but google is going to require to use SDK 32 in August for new apps.

Comment: Hello jcesarmobile, and thank you very much for this very accurate information.

But my concern is that my application, very specific, must work on two devices (Trimble TDC600) on which Android is in version 8 (API 26). It will not be deployed on GooglePay but will be installed manually with the APK.

Would using an older version of Android Studio solve my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The compileSdkVersion is just to indicate the SDK to use to compile your app, Google launches a new SDK every year and makes you use latest on submitting apps to google play. It's always compatible with older versions, so you don't have to use 26 to make your app work on SDK 26 devices, as long as your `minSdkVersion` is smaller or equal than the version you want to support. 
So, as your `minSdkVersion` is set to 26, it should work on Android 8 without problems.

Comment: Thank you jcesarmobile,

When I generate my application with minSdkVersion = 26, compileSdkVersion = 30 and targetSdkVersion = 30, it works perfectly on Android 10, but not on Android 8. 
On Android 8, it starts, the splashscreen appears and quickly the screen goes blank.

Comment: What do you mean by “goes blank”?